# LibreOffice Calc Cell Texts

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible in LibreOffice Calc to have a cell equal what another cell has including some extra text in the new cell. For example: Cell H4 contains "Hi". Cell J4 would have "=H4 + Bob". Bob would be the extra manually entered text. So the new J4 cell would read "Hi Bob".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use function Concatenate in text area ( Name could be a little diffrent because I don't use English version ). If you want use manually entered text put it in double quote.

```
=concatenate(H4;" Bob")
```

Here you have more about:
https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#CONCATENATE

Answer (score 3):

You could use the & operator:

```
=H4 & " Bob"
```

Comment: This is closer to what the question originally asks for...  does anyone know of any functional/performance issues?